# looking for an atomic/journaled page file in java

Tags: java, file-io, atomic

I am looking for an embeddable library for doing atomic file I/O from java.  I need the library to support the following features.

- basic page management -- allocate/free pages and read/write
- atomic (all or nothing) writes (basically journaled I/O)
- A simple binary page format (needs to be readable by C++)
- It does not need to be *that* fast (or concurrent), just simple and reliable.

Has anyone used something in the past which fits the bill?

**Things I have looked into**

I found the internals for the [kaha db](http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb.html) project to be useful, but development seems to have switched to a fusesoure project called [hawtdb](http://fusesource.com/forge/sites/hawtdb/community.html).  Hawt currently seems to rely memory mapped I/O which sounds good at first, but limits the size of the page file you can access to 2GB unless you go to a 64bit JVM + OS (due to JVM address space limitations).

Some alternatives I am considering are the [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) project, but I don't know if its embeddable.  I've looked into [derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (which created lots of files when run) and [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) (which seemed promising, but I didn't look too deeply).  These seemed to have relatively complex page file formats and seem to provide far more than I need.  [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) did provide docs for the page file format, but it too was a bit complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HOWL](http://howl.ow2.org/)

HOWL is a logger implementation providing features required by the ObjectWeb JOTM project, with a public API that is generally usable by any Transaction Manager. HOWL uses unformatted binary logs to maximize performance and specifies a journalization API with methods necessary to support JOTM recovery operations.

HOWL is intended to be used for logging of temporary data such as XA transaction events

Comment: This is actually an older implementation, written in part by the same author as kaha and hawt.  It is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

- [Berkley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html)?  (The traditional version with JNI, not the Java version if you also want to access via C++).  I haven't used it, but seems to fit your requirements more closely than some of the alternatives that you've listed.
- [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)? Similar but more relational database focused. Native, but with Java bindings.

Just some other ideas. These might not provide low enough access for page based file i/o though.

Comment: You might also want to watch for answers to this question in case you decided to build your own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759311/memory-mapped-files-and-atomic-writes-of-single-blocks

Comment: I have to say SQLLite really does have well commented code, it reads more like a novel than source.

Answer (score 0):

An oldie, but goodie [JDBM](http://jdbm.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Great comment in their javadoc `The set of dirty records on the in-use list constitutes a transaction. Later on, we will send these records to some recovery thingy.`